# how to convert value type [String] to [Struct] type - Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

Can help me here?
I want to convert a string type variable to a struct type.

```
var listaDeDestinos = [String]()
var listaSugerencia = [Destinos]()
```

where [Destinos] is a Struct Destinos{}

here is when appers the error:

> Cannot convert value type [String] to type [Destinos] in coercion

`listaSugerencia.append(listaDeDestinos as [Destinos])// error`

thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the declaration of Destinos

Comment: sure, here: public struct Destinos: Data {
 public var idDestino : Int?
 public var desDestino : String?
}

Comment: what value you going to set for `idDestino` if you thinking to set each object of `listaDeDestinos` as `desDestino` property

Comment: i have a list:  var listado = [Destinos]()
    
    func GetDestinos(){
        listado.append(Destinos(idDestino: 1, desDestino: "Asunción"))
        listado.append(Destinos(idDestino: 2, desDestino: "Miami"))
        listado.append(Destinos(idDestino: 3, desDestino: "Atenas"))
        listado.append(Destinos(idDestino: 4, desDestino: "Londres"))
        listado.append(Destinos(idDestino: 5, desDestino: "Madrid"))
    }

Comment: and then do this:  for object in DestinoLista.listado {
            
            if  (object.desDestino?.lowercased().contains(substring.lowercased()))! {
                listaDeDestinos.append(object.desDestino!)
                listasugerencia.append(listaDeDestinos as [Destinos])//error
                
                print(listaDeDestinos)
            }
            
        }

Answer (score 0):

i find a solution:

Instance Destinos()

`var DestinoInstancia = Destinos()`

and the use like this:

```
DestinoInstancia.desDestino = object.desDestino!
DestinoInstancia.idDestino = object.idDestino!
listasugerencia.append(DestinoInstancia)
```

thanks @Nirav D some how you help me!